# Conditional assignment with empty strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I love conditional assignment syntax in Ruby and use it all the time:

```
x = this_var || that_var
```

Right now I am working with several APIs, which return empty strings for non-existing values. Since empty string evaluates to true in Ruby I can no longer use the syntax above to set default values. It gets worse when I have several "levels" of defaults, e.g. "if this var doesn't exist set it to that var, if that doesn't exist too, set it to yet another var". So I end up doing this:

```
x = if this_var.present?
       this_var
    elsif that_var.present?
       that_var
    else
       last_resort
    end
```

The `.present?` method helps but not much. How would I write something like this in a more concise way?

I am using Rails 4 so Rails methods are welcome as an answer :)

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a library, then make that clear.

Comment: @sawa: to his credit, it's not always obvious which things are rails and not standard ruby. You can't expect him to add tags for all the gems in his gemfile.

Comment: @sawa Yeah I am using Rails but the question doesn't imply that I need a Rails method to do what I want, if there is a native Ruby one. I just happened to use a rails method in my example. I'll update the question anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is where you use `present?`'s brother, [`presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) (assuming you use rails or at least active support).

```
x = this_var.presence || that_var.presence || last_resort
```

Answer (score 5):

```
x = [this_var, that_var, last_resort].find(&:present?)
```

Comment: what about `.compact.first` ?)